# Ajax search results with result includes: Post types, Category names, Tag names, Authors etc

Tags: ajax, wordpress, search

I need to create Ajax search field with dynamic results without plugin usage, something like [this](https://ajaxsearchpro.com/category-results/).

How can I create this and include also categories, authors, tags names with links?

I'm working with this [data fetch](https://gist.github.com/alexmustin/c22b698689ce6caf9a562c3b405e2732)

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.